# How to treat CMS fields that support HTML [Django]

Tags: html, django, content-management-system

I have a Django site with a Post object like so:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True,null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=post_dir, blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.date_created.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') + ' ' + self.title)
```

which outputs body `TextField` like so in order to support HTML:

```
    {% if post.body %}
        <p>
            {{ post.body | safe }}
        </p>
    {% endif %}
```

My question is, since the admins can input HTML which could potentially malform the html (such as `post.body = '</div></div>'`), what is the best way to format and sanitize this textfield while still allowing users to input html?

Comment: What you are looking for is a RichTextField which is provided by Django CKEditor - see https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor

Comment: Cool thanks! I'm checking it out now and it seems pretty good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the desired functionality with some extras using `django-ckeditor`